# Node Compute 0-0- already exist. Select different host name or rank value. IN Rocks Centos 7

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, rocks

I am trying to make a hpc with rocks CentOS 7. After installing rocks, I have to connect the compute node to master node.

In terminal I have typed out insert-ethers to do the pxe(Preboot Execution Environment). After that I start my compute node with boot option as network pxe . After that it starts but shows this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmXHg.png)

I have also tried that I have removed the node by rock remove compute-0-0 and rocks sync config but it's not working.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Is is better adding an image directly, than a link, since web addresses change over time and the link might become invalid.

Comment: HI,https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmXHg.png

Comment: Hi , error is it show that "cannot resolve host compute-0-0.local.local.hpc.org " and after this it shows " Node compute-0-0 already exists. " But it my host or node I am adding to my cluster